# How to write a loop with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to make code like this:

```
var code1 = a, code2 = b, code3 = c;
var x = 3;

for (y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
  //this part where i dont know about
  alert ();
}
```

So how to make it alert code1, code2, and code3? I mean this alerts the values a, b, and c.
I tried with `alert("code"+y);` and `alert(code+y);` but it wont do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
 alert(window["code"+y]);
```

I would rather recommend you to use an array like

```
var code = [1, 2, 3];
for (y = 0; y < code.length; y++) {
    alert(code[y]);
}
```

Comment: This will *only* work in the global scope. If you're in any function scope, *this will not work.* While the answer is correct in theory, it would be much better to advise OP to use an object manually, instead of relying on `window`.

Comment: Scope and also just plainly teaching bad ways in javascript to a newbie could be a reason

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The question was: »So how to make it alert code1, code2, and code3?« And this code does, for what the TO asked. I find it okay, to criticize it with a comment. But as long this solution is valid, I see no reason to downvote.

Answer (score 9):

> So how to make it alert code1, code2, and code3?  i mean this alert the value a, b, and c?

The best way is to use an array instead of discrete `code1`, `code2`, and `code3` variables:

```
// (I assume a, b, and c have already been declared somewhere, or that your real
// code has literals?)
var codes = [a, b, c];
var y;

for (y = 0; y < codes.length; y++) {
  alert(codes[y]);
}
```

(Note that I started `y` in a different place.)

While it's *possible* to do the `code1`, `code2`, `code3` thing with global variables, global variables should be avoided whenever possible, and it's nearly always possible. (It's also possible with local variables, but you have to use `eval` or its cousin the `Function` constructor, and avoiding `eval` is *also* something you should avoid whenever possible, and is nearly always possible. :-) )

Alternately, if you find yourself wanting to do this where an array doesn't quite make sense, you can use an object instead:

```
var codes = {
    code1: a,
    code2: b,
    code3: c
};
var y;
for (y = 1; y <= 3; ++y) {
    alert(codes["code" + y]);
}
```

That works because in JavaScript, you can access an object property using either dot notation and a literal (`obj.foo`), or brackets notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`), and in the latter case the string can be the result of any expression. Since `"code" + y` is `code1` when `y` is `1`, `codes["code" + y]` looks up the property `"code1"` on `codes` (when `y` is `1`).

Comment: I actually think this is a "better" solution than the others but obviously not what fixes OP issue...not sure why you guys are killing him with downvotes though

Comment: you might be right from educational point of view, but that is not an answer to this question

Comment: I do not get it. Is there a downvote-outbreak? This is too a valid answer.

Comment: How does this not answer the question? The question is how to alert the values a, b, and c: *"i mean this alert the value a, b, and c"* This tells the OP the *correct* way to do that, not a way that only works for global variables, does unnecessary string concatenation, and encourages bad habits.

Comment: Agree with you T.J completely. People must of woke up on wrong side of the bed

Comment: This is getting my +1 for actually being good advice. Although, it would closer match OP's question if you used an object, like `codes = {"code1":a...}` and access with `codes["code"+y]`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Yeah, was thinking of adding that as an option. I will.

Comment: sorry everyone the thing is that code1, code2, and code3 is a parsing code of looping value from php code (using json_encode and I already try using global variable) and I cant make it into a array (because the value of this code will always overwrite one another)..or is that any other way to make the php parsing it into array??

Comment: @riyaniya: There's no reason the PHP output has to create discrete variables. If you put the code for your PHP output in the question, we can show you how to adjust it to handle whatever the issue is you're talking about with overwriting (it isn't clear from the comment above, but that's fine, just update the question). Again, I **strongly** advise not using a series of `codeX` globals for this, there really isn't any reason to.